# Do I need to install Hadoop to run Flink app on my local

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-flink

I keep on getting this message when I try to run my FLink program in IntelliJ

```
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell - Failed to detect a valid hadoop home directory
java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset.

com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: No AWS Credentials provided by BasicAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint: No AWS Credentials provided by BasicAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint
```

On searching for solutions I came across https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/ops/deployment/aws.html#aws-access-key-id-and-secret-access-key-not-specified
It talks about pointing flink to hadoop, etc. So do I need to install hadoop on my local?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the Hadoop to run Flink in general. But I assume You are using s3. Flink supports S3 via the so-called Hadoop compatibility mode. In order for this to work, You may need some additional dependencies and also You should add the `core-site.xml` to Your project where You will define :

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3.impl</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
        <value>[some-key]</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
        <value>[some-key]</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```